# Sidebar toggled that slide to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

below is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:red">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="background-color:yellow">sidebar
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
     <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle" >Press</a>    
            <div>This is a serious health setback for me personally, but one of CN's core strengths is that we have a very experienced and tightly-knit senior  <span id="counterId"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed; 
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    background: #050545;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px -7px grey;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}
```

JS

```
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

The jsfiddle is below:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xzqqebdt/1/)

As you guys can see, it is a sidebar slide to the right when I press the link. It kinda squeeze the content on the right side of the screen when I press it.

What I want is the the right side of the content to slide to the right to go behind the screen, not squeeze all content together. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give fixed `width` as the width of the `viewport` to the `#wrapper` element.

Use [`vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) to set the width.

> 1/100th of the width of the viewport.

```
#wrapper {
  ...
  width: 100vw; // vw: Viewport width when page is loaded
}
```

[More about `vw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/xzqqebdt/5/)

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  left: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #050545;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px -7px grey;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:red">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="background-color:yellow">sidebar
    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar"> <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">Press</a> 
      <div>This is a serious health setback for me personally, but one of CN's core strengths is that we have a very experienced and tightly-knit senior <span id="counterId"></span>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: same style for `#wrapper` if he wants `background-color` to be extended.

Comment: How bout for the yellow colored left side? Seems like it squeezed the content too when it slide to the left.  https://jsfiddle.net/xzqqebdt/7/  How to make it just hide underneath?

Comment: @Coolguy Then you can use `animate()` to animate the `left` of sidebar